# What does "P" mean in command listings?

Tags: skullgirls

In the command list menu several attacks, particularly supers, use "P" as a command. But there's no P button. There's HP, MP and LP for high/medium/low punches, but P doesn't seem to mean "any punch" either.

What's do I need to input to match "P" in attack commands?

Comment: http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Skullgirls#Controls_and_Notation ... looks like it might be Dash or a Forward?

Comment: @Decency Some fighting games (Marvel vs. Capcom 3, for example, and Skullgirls, naturally) have two commands for dashing: either a double-tap with the joystick, or hitting two punch buttons at the same time.  The website you specify has "->-> OR PP" as dashing, as described.

Comment: @KazDragon two punch buttons at once is definitely a dash, so maybe that's it. Perhaps I was hitting two punch buttons in succession not at once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure P means any punch (LP, MP, HP). I would check to make sure you are inputting the commands you are trying correctly and that you meet the requirements to execute the move (for example if you have enough meter to do so).

Comment: Hm maybe, I'll try in Training mode so I can test with maxed out power